# time falls b/w 2 times

Tags: excel, time

I need to check the lunch time 12:00:00 to 13:00:00 in the two given times. I have used the Median formula but it's not giving the correct result. Any help could be appreciated.

`=IF(C2=MEDIAN(A2,B2,C2),"yes","no")` this formula is not working for me

[Excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpG2H.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mentioning time along with date is a good practice.. Following formula will give incorrect results if the period spans over a day. For example, 23rd March 20:00 to 24th March 14:00.

If its not the case then..

```
=IF(AND(TIMEVALUE("13:00:00")>A3,TIMEVALUE("12:00:00")<B3),"YES","NO")
```

Edit1: as per your comment below

```
=IF(DAY(A7)=DAY(B7),AND(TIMEVALUE("13:00:00")>MOD(A7,1),TIMEVALUE("12:00:00")<MOD(B7,1)),OR(TIMEVALUE("13:00:00")>MOD(A7,1),TIMEVALUE("12:00:00")<MOD(B7,1)))
```

[image]

Edit2: Earlier formula would give any part of the intersection with lunch hour. So, it would be true if the end time is 12:00 or start time is 13:00. Following is the corrected formula as per your comment below. It will make sure that full lunch hour (12:00 to 13:00) falls between the start and end time. For partial intersection it will return false. So, if the start time or the end time falls between 12:00 to 13:00 it will return false. It will check for FULL LUNCH HOUR.

```
=IF(DAY(A7)=DAY(B7),AND(TIMEVALUE("12:00:00")>MOD(A7,1),TIMEVALUE("13:00:00")<MOD(B7,1)),IF(DAY(B7)>DAY(A7),OR(TIMEVALUE("12:00:00")>MOD(A7,1),TIMEVALUE("13:00:00")<MOD(B7,1)),"Check Dates"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Naresh. But ,Unfortunately we have two check the time like that only( 23rd March 20:00 to 24th March 14:00). In this time period we have to check that 12:00:00 -13:00:00 falls or not.

Comment: I have added the excel data clearly, could please check and suggest any other formula.

Comment: Thank you, almost it's satisfied all the conditions except the below 2. 
1) ST = 2019-10-16 13:00:00,  ET= 2019-10-16 15:30:00 giving as TRUE
2) ST= 2019-10-18 13:00:00, ET=2019-10-19 1:00:00 giving as TRUE

Comment: edited answer, please check... Its about the time in the formula. You can see 12:00 and 13:00. I have just interchanged those in the new formula assuming you want to check full lunch hour intersection. If you still want to check the partial intersection then keep the function as it is. Just replace 12:00 by 12:01 and 13:00 by 12:59. Also notice in the new formula, I have added condition to make sure that if the end day is not the same it is subsequent.

Answer (score 1):

Median returns the exact middle value.

Use the `AND` function like this:

`=IF(AND(C2>A2,C2<B2),"yes","no")`

note that your 01:00 time will result in a `false` value