# I need to average cells in a column based on the time of day in another column in excel, i.e. morning, afternoon and night

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, average

I am trying to get the averages of a column that meet certain criteria into a single cell.
The following formula works: =AVERAGEIFS(tblData[Sys],tblData[Time],">=12:00 PM",tblData[Time],"<6:00 PM") but when I adjust the time values to: =AVERAGEIFS(tblData[Sys],tblData[Time],">=6:00 PM",tblData[Time],"<4:00 AM") I get an error. I'm guessing it's because the time range goes into the next day.
Is there a better function to use or a workaround?

Comment: What values are actually in the `[Time]` column?  (i.e. what do you see if you format the cell as `General`?)

Comment: [Time] is formatted as Time. There is also a Date Column that I don't really care about but might be useful

Comment: If I format as General I just see decimal numbers representing the times

Comment: If every value is less than one, the algorithm would be, if 2nd time less than 1st time, then compare with 1+ the 2nd time. You won't be able to use `AVERAGEIFS`. If no one answers, I will work on it in the morning.

Comment: Thanks, I tried wrapping it in an OR statement and using numbers less than 1, i.e. >6pm or < 6 am but couldn't make it work. Just to be clear, I need the avg of all [Sys] entries between 6pm and 6 am to display in only one cell.

Comment: something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61096277/9808063) ?

Answer (score 1):

This formula seems to work for you scenario.  It checks for the possibility that the end time is before the start time (but on the next day) and changes the logic accordingly:

```
=AVERAGE(
      IF(
        IF(tmStart>=tmEnd,
                  (tblData[Time]>=tmStart)+(tblData[Time]<=tmEnd),
                  (tblData[Time]>=tmStart)*(tblData[Time]<=tmEnd))
          =1,tblData[Sys],""))
```

[image]

Comment: What you've done is exactly what I want but it's not working for me. Is the tmStart,tmEnd it's own separate table and how is it formatted, (Time, General, etc.)?  I am using Excel 2010 if that matters.

Comment: @chrisr they are just named ranges (single cell) containing the obvious. Formatting is irrelevant. You can see in my screenshot how I formatted, but You can use any format you want. Just make sure you have the correct value in there. Times are stored by Excel as fractions of the day. Formatting only effects what we see.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand this function does, and the underlying intentions are - I elaborate in the what follows, proffer a workable solution, provide a reconciliation, as well as a link to the workbook with screenshot below.

You will need to specify # days spanned - even the scenario that 'worked' for you (i.e.. `=AVERAGEIFS(tblData[Sys],tblData[Time],">=12:00 PM",tblData[Time],"<6:00 PM")`  could, in theory, span 2 (or more) days.  The fact that this 'works' (doesn't return #DIV/0!) is that the 'intersection' of conditions is an non-empty set (i.e. {12pm-5pm}).

As I say, if this was intended to be ">=12:00" from day 1 through to "<6pm" the following, there is no way of determining whether this is indeed the case by simply 'comparing the times' (e.g. 12pmvs 6pm).

Screenshot/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98GlIcm1x0DaYWxWI?e=djpQou) refer::

[image: Screenshot - scenario B, Multiple days = 'Y']

```
=IF($I$5="Y",(SUM(1*($C$5:$C$28*(($D$5:$D$28>=$J$3)+1*($D$5:$D$28<$K$3)))))/SUM((($D$5:$D$28>=$J$3)+1*($D$5:$D$28<$K$3))),IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(C5:C28,D5:D28,">="&J3,D5:D28,"<"&K3),"times don't intersect! "))
```

where: I5 = 'Y' or 'N' (i.e. multiple days'). When scenario B is selected, with multiple days = 'Y', outcome = 12.9 which reconciles to a manual calculation.